# JPA CriteriaBuilder ManyToOne and null values

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api, many-to-one

I'm trying to create a `Specification` for filtering a table. This table has 2 `@ManyToOne` relationships (that can be null) and I'd like to apply the filter inside them. Like a search function.

Assume this structure

```java
public class X {
   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = A.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "aID")
   private A a;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = B.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "bID")
   private B b;
}
```

Also assume that `A` and `B` have a `String` attribute called **name**.

So, what I want to make a `Specification` for `X` where I can match a `String` value across the **name** of `A` or `B`.

This was my approach:

```java
public static Specification<X> filterName(String value) {
   return new Specification<X>() {
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<X> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    
         Expression<String> aName = root.get("a").get("name").as(String.class);
         Expression<String> bName = root.get("b").get("name").as(String.class);

         List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

         if (!value.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(builder.like(aName, "%" + value + "%"));
            predicates.add(builder.like(bName, "%" + value + "%"));
         }else{
            return null;
         }

         Predicate predicate = builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
         return predicate;
      }
   };
}
```

I was really hoping it will work, but it did not.

What I would like is to display those rows where the **name** of A `OR` the **name** of B is `like` the input value.

If I enable the logs to display the SQL query this is what I get:

> select xentity0_.aId, xentity0_.bId from table_x xtab cross join table_a atab cross join table_b btab where xtab.aId=atab.id and xtab.bId=btab.id and (atab.name like ?) and (btab.name like ?)

I think the problem is with the `where xtab.aId=atab.id and xtab.bId=btab.id` part. Because as `A` or `B` can be null, then not always that condition is met.

Assume this table for `X`:

| ID | aId | bId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | null |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

this table for `A`:

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Lucy |

this table for `B`:

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Luke |
| 2 | Mike |

When looking for **%Lu%** using the `Specification` for `X` what I would like to see is

| ID | aId | bId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

because of **Lucy** in `A` and **Luke** in `B`. Instead what I see is the last row (where both `A` and `B` are not null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, `CriteriaBuilder` is using cross join by default (what you have mentioned about BTW). That's the reason why it will not get the data where `A` or `B` is `null`. You can get those records by setting `Join` type to `LEFT`:

```
root.join(Entity.childEntity, JoinType.LEFT)
```

In your case, try to modify your code as below:

```
Expression<String> aName = root.join("a", JoinType.LEFT).get("name").as(String.class);
Expression<String> bName = root.join("b", JoinType.LEFT).get("name").as(String.class);
```

Beside of that, I would recommend to use `MetaModel` for `CriteriaBuilder`.

To not create and maintain Metamodel classes manually, you can use one of available generators, like `Hibernate JPA Metamodel Generator`, `OpenJPA`, `EclipseLink` or `DataNucleus`.

I personally prefer `Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel Generator`. To use it, the only thing you need to do is to add the dependency to pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the following code under `annotationProcessorPaths`:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
          <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
        </path>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

After that, when you build your application with Maven, Metamodels for all Entitiers will be automatically built.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did solve it the way you mention, with the left join. Anyway I will accept your answer for further references to others. About MetaModel, I try to use them time ago, but I needed to create that metamodel manually for each entity. Is there a way to auto-create it? and keep it updated?

Comment: @sebasira of course there is. I have edited my answer (added some info regarding metamodel generators)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to implement it and get back to you just let you know how it was.